# How to get favicon icon when create shortcut of website page

Tags: browser, shortcut

When I drag and drop a website onto my desktop, how can I make Firefox use the icon native to that website instead of the default firefox icon?

I have even gone painstakingly (SEVERAL TIMES) to the sites with IE, dragged the site onto my desktop in order to obtain the site native icons for my desktop (and deleted the ones with the Firefox icon) .... but they all soon revert to the default Firefox icon.

E X T R E M E L Y F R U S T R A T I N G  !!!!!!!!!

Is it true Shortcut icon as native icon untill my internet connection is open?  then after convert it to default browser icon.

I need to set my favicon of website should be set as shortcut icon when someone make its shortcut.  sometime I got favicon icon as shortcut icon, bt after certain period of time it automatically convert in to firefox default icon.

plz share if any solution found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting absolute path and not relative path:

```
 <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="http://www.mydomain.com/myicon.ico"/>
```

Also, where did you put the image. From what I recall, it will automatically pull from a certain location on your server depending on the web browser.

Add to create shortcut of your web page in Google Chrome browser :

Click on Right Corner Three row icon >>

Go To tools >>

and Click on Create Application shortcut .

It will create awesome shortcut( without address bar when you open it) and set favicon as shortcut icon.

For FireFox :: Drag and drop earthicon of address bar As you did it..